# register simple service implementation with Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

This is my controller constructor:

```
    public PostCategoryController(ICategorizationRepository<PostCategory> categorizationRepository,
                                                         IContentRepository<Post> repository, PostUtilityService postUtilityService)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _categorizationRepository = categorizationRepository;
        _postUtilityService = postUtilityService;
    }
```

How does one register the implementation for `PostUtilityService` with Autofac? This service has no interface, it's just a class performing some actions.

I want to use the `Register` method or overload that is the simplest or the best performance-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AsSelf` extension method.

```
builder.RegisterType<PostUtilityService>().AsSelf();
```

Comment: `AsSelf()` can be omitted if it is the only service provided by the component, but reads nicely here :)